# Where to find open tabular hyperspectral data for machine learning research?

Tags: data, machine-learning, hyperspectral-sensor

Where can i find open datasets regarding " Wheat/Maize Leaf Spectra with Associated water content, Potassium and Nitrogen Measurements" for machine learning research i.e. hyperspectral tabular data collected from a field spectroradiometer along with chemical parameters.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Your question is most welcome here too as there are many experts in hyperspectral remote sensing at GIS SE.